# What's causing, "Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127" when trying to export radialnetwork to HTML?

Tags: r, htmlwidgets, networkd3, radial

I am trying to export a networkD3 plot, a radialnetwork plot, to an HTML file in RStudio, but am unable to export the plot.  Is anyone else getting an R code execution error when trying to export as HTML?  I don't know what is causing this issue.

```
 Error: pandoc document conversion failed with error 127
```

I can export as various formats, PNG/JPEG/BMP in various resolutions, but would like to keep the GUI for the radial network and export it as an HTML or any file format that can keep the ability to interact with the plot.

In Rstudio, the graph has a gui in the viewer, and I can rollover certain nodes, how can I export and keep that ability?

Comment: I think error 127 was memory related, on Windows machines RStudio comes with the 32bit version of pandoc (don't know what the situation is for Linux). You might want to replace it (RStudio\bin\pandoc) with the [64bit version](https://pandoc.org/installing.html).

Comment: @ismirsehregal Yup, that is definitely one way to go, thanks.  64-Bit pandoc did solve my problem using pandoc to export it.  It is faster and cleaner than this other way: I have realized to circumvent this error is to use an RMarkdown and save it as an HTML Presentation(Slide with Plot).

Comment: For future readers: find the zip files at the bottom of the page [here](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases/latest) -> assets

Comment: It seems this was already taken into account by now: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/pull/4051